# Cannot connect to my VPN service

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

"Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request"

I tried reinstalling openvpn and network manager, and tried different ovpn profiles and made sure I entered the correct login information...

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall network-manager-gnome`. Log out and back in, or reboot. This should create an `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop` that will autostart the necessary service for this. See [Carlo's answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/11485/13077) below, and [this Bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1394977).

Answer (score 3):

Finally got the VPN working after finding the answer in the following link:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1394977

The network manager somehow uses **nm-applet** (which does not run by default) to access the VPN secrets.

You can add nm-applet in the **System Settings > Applications > Startup** by adding the custom command **/usr/bin/nm-applet**

Comment: If you want to run this now (ie without relogging in or rebooting) simply run `/usr/bin/nm-applet > /dev/null 2>&1 &` from a shell. If you run it as it is, you'll get no end of bitching from Gtk. You can kill it as soon as you've connected to your VPN.

Comment: Turns out I had "deleted" nm-applet from my elementaryOS _Applications_ → _Startup_ configuration. This creates a `~/.config/autostart/nm-applet.deskop` with the key `NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;Pantheon`. I probably thought "hmm, probably don't need that." Yeah, no. It is what makes the openconnect VPN able to prompt you for your password. Delete this file, log out and back in, and the applet will autostart by virtue of there being a `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop` that comes with the network-manager-gnome package.

Answer (score 0):

openvpn seems to have some troubles getting the things right, I managed to log in to vpn service with pptp protocol ( seems it's doing the right setup )

Answer (score 0):

I always install software-properties-gtk after installing Elementary OS and encounter this issue everytime with PPTP.

After reinstalling ElementaryOS the last time, I decided to skip installing software-properties-gtk and never encountered the issue since. Even after multiple restarts.

I think the software-properties-gtk package breaks the VPN configuration tool since I was able to connect to a VPN (PPTP) using a fresh live USB of Elementary OS without issues.  The software-properties-gtk has been removed from Ubuntu 16.04 and might be causing issues with the newer packages of Ubuntu.

Comment: Nevermind. My VPN suddenly stopped working again.